# Como garantir que uma SESSION expire caso o usuário acesse uma cópia da aplicação que está em um outro diretório

Tags: php, session

Tenho uma aplicação em php onde utilizo sessions para controle do login.
A aplicação está em meusite.com/minhaApp (vou chamar de App1)
Ocorre que para testes eu criei uma instância da minha aplicação em outro diretório.

meusite.com/outroDir/minhaApp  (vou chamar de App2)

Depois que fiz está modificação, verifiquei que uma vez criado um acesso e armazenado uma SESSION, caso o usuário acesse App1 e depois mude a url para acessar App2.  A mesma SESSION permanece ativa. Fazendo com que meu controle de login falhe.

Alguém teria uma dica para lidar com isso? Teria que fazer alguma verificação de variável de ambiente do servidor como HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: Seria muito melhor separar as "hospedagens" locais pra faciltar a vida. Inclusive pq esse tipo de "organização" em pastas geralmente não organiza muito as coisas se na hospedagem definitiva a aplicação for ficar na raiz do site (geralmente as pessoas usam caminhos relativos onde deveria ser absoluto justamente por causa das pastas). Duas soluções mais óbvias pra fazer testes são a "hospedagem" em portas diferentes, ou melhor ainda, criar URLs de teste no "hosts" do sistema apontando pro 127.0.0.1 (ex: app1.bruno e app2.bruno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de mudar a lógica do sistema, uma solução simples é você mudar o nome do *cookie* de sessão de acordo com a pasta, **antes** do `session_start()`.

Fazendo isso, você tem sessões totalmente independentes, mas simultâneas:

```
 <?php
    // inicio do bloco de teste
    $independentes = array( 'app1', 'app2' );

    $caminho = explode( '/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );
    $appnumber = array_search( $caminho[1], $independentes );
    session_name( 'PHPSID_'.( $appnumber === false ? 0 : $appnumber + 1 ) );
    // fim do bloco de teste

    session_start();
```

Basicamente estamos pegando o segundo ítem do caminho dividido pelas barras (o primeiro é vazio, pois o `PATH_INFO` começa com `/`), localizando a posição dele num *array* com o nome das pastas, e adicionando sua posição ao nome do *cookie* de sessão, fazendo com que cada situação tenha uma sessão totalmente independente.

PS: Se não estiver usando CGI nem Apache, troque o `PATH_INFO` por `REQUEST_URI`.

No caso, compensa criar um include com as linhas do bloco de teste, e dar um `require_once()` nas suas páginas que usam sessão. Fazendo isso, você pode testar quantas pastas diferentes quiser com sessões independentes, simultaneamente. Basta colocar o nome da pasta raiz de cada uma das aplicações no lugar de `app1` e `app2` no array.

Exemplo:

```
aplicação 0 em   http://127.0.0.1/...
aplicação 1 em   http://127.0.0.1/teste_a/...
aplicação 2 em   http://127.0.0.1/teste_b/...
aplicação 3 em   http://127.0.0.1/teste_c/...
```

Configuração:

```
$independentes = array( 'teste_a', 'teste_b', 'teste_c' );
```

Tudo que estiver fora dos caminhos `teste_a`, `teste_b`  e `teste_c`, ou em caminhos que não estejam na lista, vai ser considerado como parte da aplicação padrão (`0`).

### Reaproveitando em várias páginas:

Pra aplicar a solução em várias páginas, pode salvar esse arquivo como session_start.php, por exemplo:

```
<?php
   $independentes = array( 'app1', 'app2' );

   $caminho = explode( '/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );
   $appnumber = array_search( $caminho[1], $independentes );
   session_name( 'PHPSID_'.( $appnumber === false ? 0 : $appnumber + 1 ) );

   session_start();
```

E simplesmente usar com `require_once()` em todas as páginas, no lugar do `session_start()` original:

```
<?php
   require_once( 'session_start.php' );

   // ... resto do seu código  ... //
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sobre o `HTTP_REFERER`:**

O `HTTP_REFERER` é extremamente vulnerável neste caso. Uma vez que ele pode ser editado e apagado com tranquilidade no lado do cliente, portanto não acredite nele, você pode usar o `HTTP_REFERER` como um complemento, mas não unicamente ele.

> Nota: Se o usuário copiar o link e abrir uma nova página o `Referer` irá deixar de existir, apenas como complemento existem plugins para eliminar `Referer`, por motivos de privacidade.

**Correção do problema:**

Supondo que exista:

```
meusite.com/App1/index.php
meusite.com/App2/index.php
meusite.com/OutroDir/App3/index.php
```

A forma mais fácil seria comparar se a sessão tem acesso ao `App` que deseja.

Por exemplo:

```
// Restringe acesso ao App1:
   $acesso = array('App1');    
   $_SESSION['acesso'] = $acesso;

// Restringe acesso ao App1 e App2:
   $acesso = array('App1', 'App2');    
   $_SESSION['acesso'] = $acesso;
```

Dessa forma determina que o usuário terá acesso somente ao App1 e no outro caso o usuário teria acesso ao App1 e também ao App2.

Dessa forma, os seus aplicativos (`App1`, `App2` e `App3`) teriam que verificar se o usuário está ou não autorizado a fazer isso.

Você pode usar algo desta forma:

```
function VerificarSessao($FSession, $FApp){

   return in_array($FApp, $FSession);

}
```

Então chame por:

```
$Autorizado = VerificarSessao( $_SESSION['acesso'] , basename(__DIR__) );

if($Autorizado){
  echo 'Você pode acessar!";
}else{
  echo 'Você não pode acessar!";
}
```

Dessa forma você irá verificar se o diretorio (no caso /App1, /App2, /App3) estão autorizados na sua sessão.

> Nota: Eu preferir por criar a função exigindo passar os dois parâmetros para que compreendesse o funcionamento de forma mais clara, por isso está extremamente simples, porém poderá colocar um `header('location: /erro.php'); exit;` dentro da função ao invés de retornar `true`/`false`, por exemplo. Enfim.